# TypeError: 'key' is an invalid keyword argument for this function for sorting image

Tags: python, opencv, yolo

I'm trying to crop a bounded image from yolo but it's giving me this error

```
def firstCrop(img, predictions):
    predictions.sort(key=lambda x: x.get('confidence'))
    xtop = predictions[-1].get('topleft').get('x')
    ytop = predictions[-1].get('topleft').get('y')
    xbottom = predictions[-1].get('bottomright').get('x')
    ybottom = predictions[-1].get('bottomright').get('y')
    firstCrop = img[ytop:ybottom, xtop:xbottom]
    cv2.rectangle(img,(xtop,ytop),(xbottom,ybottom),(0,255,0),3)
    return firstCrop
```

AT this line

```
 predictions.sort(key=lambda x: x.get('confidence'))
```

TypeError: 'key' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: And `predictions` is an object of which type?

Comment: prediction is an image that has the bounding box while img is image without  prediction or bounding box

Comment: Could you give a descriptions for programmers? What is the type of `predictions` (like `print(type(predictions))`? In other words: How do you know that `predictions` has a `sort` method and how did you get the idea that this method has a parameter `key`?

Comment: <class 'numpy.ndarray'>
this the type of predictions and img

Comment: According to the documentation [`numpy.ndarray.sort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html#numpy.ndarray.sort) doesn't have a `key` parameter.

Comment: We're missing part of the error message, and a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeError: 'key' is an invalid keyword argument for this function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55950153/typeerror-key-is-an-invalid-keyword-argument-for-this-function)